# How can i move my mouse on a website using selnium (or any other webdriver) by giving x,y coordinates

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyautogui

```
while True:
    cursorx, cursory = pyautogui.position()
    body = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body")
    actions.move_to_element_with_offset(body, cursorx, cursory)
```

How can i move the mouse around on the site freely without an element? (Without me interacting with it like in the background or so.
It's written in python with the pyautogui to get the position of the cursor.

Comment: Selenium was not designed with this scenario in mind. What is it you are trying to do and why can't you reference an element?

Comment: @JeffC because I'm making a bot for a game that requires it.

Comment: That's still not a lot of info. So the game is an HTML5 app or ?

Answer (score 0):

Just input the coordinates into pyautogui's moveTo method:

```
pyautogui.moveTo(x=1043, y=606)
```